# How to generate electricity from clockwise or counterclockwise rotation?

Tags: dc-motor

Can something that rotates freely in space generate electricty when it spins from both the clockwise and counterclockwise direction, or could you only draw electricity from a clockwise rotation?  What's rotating is something like a water wheel, but it can tilt and rotate in either direction, and actually does.

Comment: Well usually the reverse of a motor is a generator, as a changing magnetic field from the rotation causes an alternating current. If you turn the spindle of a motor, watch the output of its terminals on an oscilloscope. Essentially, the way you turn it affects the polarity of the voltage, which is really just the phase since its AC. Attach those terminals to a full bridge rectifier and it doesnt matter which way you turn.

Comment: Clockwise and counter-clockwise are relative...if you look at the rotation from the other end of the axis it appears to be reversed. So, of course you can generate electricity in either direction.

Comment: Need a sketch.  It has to be rotating in relation to something, and you need some sort of connection to that something.

Comment: Concentrating on the "freely in space" section: If an object e.g. a permanent magnet is rotating "freely in space" there is nothing to stop it, so it will keep rotating . However as soon as you take energy out the rotation will diminish and ultimately stop.

Answer (score 2):

Electric generators can generally generate electricity with either direction of rotation. A DC generator with a commutator will reverse the plus-minus polarity of the output when the direction of rotation is reversed. There may be some types of generator that are designed for a specific direction of operation, but either direction could be selected in the design stage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A permanent magnet DC generator will produce a current with either direction of rotation.

Comment: Just the polarity of the current will be different. But AC motors do that all the time anyways already just spinning in direction. So you can just rectify if you need it to be a certain polarity.